# How can I align div background images that have diagonal edges?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have to create a menu bar that has diagonal background images.

I've tried everything, but divs are rectangular and is not working so well.

Here is what I must achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KsL7.jpg

and this is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/z304mkoj/

```
enter code here
```

For now, just ignore the texts that are not aligned, I will deal with that later :)

I am wondering what can I do to make the diagonal images fit side by side, is it even possible?

All I have is the .psd with the design and the layers, and now I must convert it to HTML / CSS

Comment: Would it be easier to just put the diagonal images in one image and load that as the background of the parent div then line up the text of the child divs with their diagonal image on the parent?

Comment: why do you need those images at all, you can do this all with css.

Comment: How could I make it using css? That would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins!

This got it looking just about right for me. :)

```
#leftedgebutton 
{ 
     width: 180px;
     height: 45px;
} 

#leftbutton 
{ 
     /*left: 283px; 
     top: 0px; 
     position: absolute;*/ 
     width: 150px;
     height: 45px;
     margin-left: -50px;
     margin-right: -30px;
} 

#rightbutton 
{ 
     /*left: 867px; 
     top: 0; 
     position: absolute;*/ 
     width: 150px;
     height: 45px;
     margin-left: -30px;
}

 #rightedgebutton 
{ 
     /*left: 986px; 
     top: 0; 
     position: absolute;*/ 
     width: 180px;
     height: 45px;
     margin-left: -50px;
}

#toplogoarea 
{ 
     /*left: 396px; 
     top: -12px; 
     position: absolute;*/ 
     width: 507px;
     height: 191px;
     z-index:190;
} 

#dfgameslogo 
{ 
     /*left: 581px; 
     top: 58px; 
     position: absolute;*/ 
     width: 136px;
     height: 127px;
}

#searchbar 
{ 
     width: 474px;
     height: 45px;
}
```